# Vim (gvim) display of box-drawing extended 8-bit ascii codes

Tags: windows, vim

I have a file that looks like this in notepad.exe:

[image: ascii-notepad]

But it looks like this in gvim.exe on windows 7:

[image: ascii-gvim]

With `:set encoding=utf-8` it looks like this:

[image: ascii-gvim-utf-8]

How to tell gvim that the extended ascii chars should be displayed as the box chars?

Thanks!

It was necessary to put the following into the vimrc file (or in my case gvimrc):

```
let &guifont='Lucida_Console:h8'
set encoding=utf-8
```

It was the font and the encoding.  I wasn't able to change it on the fly during an editing session in the vim command-line mode.  It seems necessary to have these set during vim startup.

Thanks svlasov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set encoding to UTF-8:

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: Hmm, I had tried that but no luck.  Have added utf-8 screenshot to the question.

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: guifont is Ti92Pluspc:h8.  I tried other fonts with no success.

Comment: What is the file encoding? Open it in any browser, set encoding to Unicode and check that it displays correctly. If not, convert it to Unicode or set the corresponding encoding in Vim.

Comment: Okay, yes.  It was necessary to put the following into the vimrc file (or in my case gvimrc):

    let &guifont='Lucida_Console:h8'
    set encoding=utf-8

It was the font and the encoding.  I wasn't able to change it on the fly during an editing session in the vim command-line mode.  It seems necessary to have these set during vim startup.